# Truncate all MySQL columns in table apart from the first

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hey guys as you can see I have this PHP script:

```
    <?php
    $databasehost = "localhost"; 
    $databasename = ""; 
    $databasetable = ""; 
    $databaseusername=""; 
    $databasepassword = ""; 
    $fieldseparator = ","; 
    $lineseparator = "\n";
    $enclosedbyquote = '"';
    $csvfile = "file.csv";

    if(!file_exists($csvfile)) {
        die("File not found. Make sure you specified the correct path.");
    }

    try {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$databasehost;dbname=$databasename", 
            $databaseusername, $databasepassword,
            array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
            )
        );
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("database connection failed: ".$e->getMessage());
    }

    $pdo->exec("TRUNCATE TABLE `$databasetable`");

        $affectedRows = $pdo->exec("
        LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$pdo->quote($csvfile)." REPLACE INTO TABLE `$databasetable`
        FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ".$pdo->quote($enclosedbyquote)."
         TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldseparator)." 
        LINES TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($lineseparator)." 
        IGNORE 1 LINES");

    echo "Loaded a total of $affectedRows records from this csv file.\n";

    ?>
```

Now as you can see this is importing a csv file into my database and truncating the whole SQL table.

My question is how can I stop the first column of the table from being effected by the import? I am going to use the first column as an ID, any idea how I could do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Rather than:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `$databasetable`
```

use:

```
UPDATE `$databasetable` SET colB = '', colC = '', colD = '', colE = '';
```

where colA is the column you want to preserve. If you are using NULL fields, change to:

```
    UPDATE `$databasetable` SET colB = NULL; #etc.
```